Why CSS file working for index and not for campaigns on Flask?
I'm trying to make an project on Flask here is the code below.
My directory is like this

from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,request,redirect
import pymongo

app= Flask(__name__,static_url_path='', 
            static_folder='static',
            )

@app.route('/admin')
def index():
    return render_template('admin/index.html')

@app.route('/admin/campaigns')
def campaigns():
    return render_template('admin/campaigns.html')


You need to say exactly what isn't working e.g. an image isn't being displayed, the style isn't being applied, etc. You also need to show the relevant code on campaigns.html for the static objects that you say isn't working

Is adminn (double n) intentional?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

both the css and image not working
